# Solving a differential equation with Shooting

Tags: differential-equations, numerics

So I have a differential equation that I do not expect to solve analytically. I have been trying a few numerical methods, most recently shooting, without any luck.
Appologies for showing the equation but it reads

\begin{equation}
 \sqrt{\frac{l_4^4 r(\sigma )^2 \cosh ^2(\sigma ) \left(k l_3^2+\cosh ^2(\sigma ) r'(\sigma )^2+r(\sigma )^2\right)}{l_3^2 \left(k l_3^2+r(\sigma )^2\right)}} \left(-2 r(\sigma )^2 \left(k l_3^2+\cosh ^2(\sigma ) r'(\sigma )^2\right)-k l_3^2 \left(k l_3^2+\cosh ^2(\sigma ) r'(\sigma )^2\right)+r(\sigma ) \cosh (\sigma ) \left(k l_3^2 \left(\cosh (\sigma ) r''(\sigma )+3 \sinh (\sigma ) r'(\sigma )\right)+2 \sinh (\sigma ) \cosh ^2(\sigma ) r'(\sigma )^3\right)+r(\sigma )^3 \cosh (\sigma ) \left(\cosh (\sigma ) r''(\sigma )+3 \sinh (\sigma ) r'(\sigma )\right)-r(\sigma )^4\right)=0
\end{equation}

The reason I do not copy paste the Mathematca code for this is because even with RawInput it messes up the formal. I call the above equation "eq" in my code.

I have the boundary conditions $r(0) =0, r(b)= L$ and $r'(c) = \infty$ where $b$ and $c$ are two fixed points.

Then I copied pasted the code from a Wolfram website [here](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NDSolveBVP.html) but replaced their boundary conditions with mine.

The code is

```
sols = Map[
First[NDSolve[{D[L, r[σ]] - 
D[D[L, r'[σ]], σ] == 0, r[0] == 0, 
r[Subscript[σ, 0]] == L}, r, σ, 
 Method -> {"Shooting", 
 "StartingInitialConditions" -> {r[0] == 0, 
 r'[0] == #}}]] &, {1.5, 1.75, 2}];
 Plot[Evaluate[r[σ] /. sols], {σ, 0, 10}, 
 PlotStyle -> {Black, Blue, Green}]
```

But I get an error message saying "NDSolve::overdet: There are fewer dependent variables, {r[σ]}, than equations, so the system is overdetermined." and "ReplaceAll::reps: {<<1>>} is neither a list of replacement rules nor a valid dispatch table, and so cannot be used for replacing."

Any ideas on how I could proceed from here?

Also, I am interested in getting the solution, not just a plot..

P.S the code for the differential equation is

```
Sqrt[(Cosh[σ]^2*r[σ]^2*Subscript[l, 4]^4*(r[σ]^2 + k*Subscript[l, 3]^2 + 
Cosh[σ]^2*Derivative[1][r][σ]^2))/(Subscript[l, 3]^2*(r[σ]^2 + 
k*Subscript[l, 3]^2))]*
(-r[σ]^4 - 2*r[σ]^2*(k*Subscript[l, 3]^2 + Cosh[σ]^2*Derivative[1][r][σ]^2) - 
k*Subscript[l, 3]^2*(k*Subscript[l, 3]^2 + Cosh[σ]^2*Derivative[1][r][σ]^2) + 
Cosh[σ]*r[σ]^3*(3*Sinh[σ]*Derivative[1][r][σ] + 
Cosh[σ]*Derivative[2][r][σ]) + 
Cosh[σ]*r[σ]*(2*Cosh[σ]^2*Sinh[σ]*Derivative[1][r][σ]^3 + 
k*Subscript[l, 3]^2*(3*Sinh[σ]*Derivative[1][r][σ] + 
Cosh[σ]*Derivative[2][r][σ])))
```

Here is a ppicture of the geometry. It might be that I need to solve this in two different branches and join the functions together by a matcing condition. [image]

Comment: It would be helpful if you provide runable code! Several parameters `k,l3,l4,...`aren't defined

Comment: Maybe avoid `Subscript`.  E.g. `y[x]` and `Subscript[x,0]` both look like functions that depend on `x`.  Maybe not what you want. -- This reproduces the error: `NDSolve[{r''[s] + r[s] == 0, r[0] == 0, r[Subscript[s, 0]] == 1}, r, s]`, that is, with `Subscript[s, 0]` having no numeric value. Probably it's the same in your case. You need a numeric boundary point.

Comment: Looks like your notation for sigma as \[Sigma] is interfering with interpreting $r[\sigma]$.  You can type Greek letters directly without this notation by pressing ESC then enter the greek letter name such as sigma then ESC likewise for the other letters.

Comment: Hi @josh, I am actually copying and pasting the raw input text, which automatically messesd up the format. Someone very kindly helped me edit it now.

Comment: @PhilL Boundary condition `r[0]==0` is singular. What do you know about points `b` and `c`?

Comment: @AlexTrounev. Not very much, I just uploaded a figure. It might be that I need to solve this in two different branches, and then join the solution together by a matching condition.